# Mongo query to return documents when sub-document array contains common data

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a mongo query to return documents which have exact same email from cat1 and cat2 source.

Please help. I am including a sample collection schema with expected matching document

Sample Collection

```
{
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "John",
        "contacts" : [
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat1",
            "detail": aa@yahoo.com
                },
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat1",
            "detail": john@yahoo.com
                },
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat2",
            "detail": john@yahoo.com
                }
        ]
},
{
        "id" : "2",
        "name" : "Bell",
        "contacts" : [
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat1",
            "detail": jj@yahoo.com
                },
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat2",
            "detail": john@yahoo.com
                }
        ]
},

{
        "id" : "3",
        "name" : "Sam",
        "contacts" : [
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat1",
            "detail": exmaple@yahoo.com
                },
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat3",
            "detail": exmaple@yahoo.com
                }
        ]
}
```

Expected result is following because this is the document which have a common email address john@yahoo.com from both source cat1 and cat2.

Document with id 2 should not be returned because though they both have email from cat1 and cat2 source the email addresses are different.

Document with id 3 should not be returned because through the email addresses are same their category is not cat1 and cat2.

```
{
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "John",
        "contacts" : [
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat1",
            "detail": aa@yahoo.com
                },
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat1",
            "detail": john@yahoo.com
                },
                {
                        "type" : "email",
                        "source": "cat2",
            "detail": john@yahoo.com
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Both documents have arrays with the same "cat" source, so why would only one document be returned? Is this meant to represent the "intersection" of the two? Would the only element intersecting not instead **just** be the "cat1" data? Are you expecting all "intersections" from the collection? Or are you just interested in "intersections" with the first document only? Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to be a lot more clear than this when asking questions of your peers.

Comment: Your question title seems different with your question content. To meet your question content, try `> db.collection.find({$and: [{'contacts.source': 'cat1'}, {'contacts.source': 'cat2'}]})` through `$and` operator.

Comment: @zangw this does not compare the fact that both cat1 and cat2 email address is the same email address.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use plain JavaScript codes to filter the same email from cat1 and cat2.

```
> db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
        var cat1Email = new Set(); 
        var cat2Email = new Set(); 

        doc.contacts.forEach(function(c){
            if (c.source === 'cat1'){
                // save the cat1 emails
                cat1Email.add(c.detail); 
                if (cat2Email.has(c.detail)){
                    // if there is same email from cat2, print this document 
                    return printjson(doc);
                }
            }else if(c.source === 'cat2'){
                // save cat2 email
                cat2Email.add(c.detail); 
                if (cat1Email.has(c.detail)){
                    // if there is same email from cat1, print this document
                    return printjson(doc)
                }
            }
        }); 
    })
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I am actually trying to get to a solution which will be a bit more robust in terms of using it from .NET level. I am fairly new with Mongo, but was thinking if I need to use aggregation framework someway to achieve this.

Comment: @Raki, I try to solve it through aggregation, but I failed. Hope someone will point out through aggregation.